# Automatically Update Fusion Table every 15 Minutes (API 1.0 + OAuth 2.0)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

I am new to the Fusion Table API v1.0 with OAuth 2.0 and need to automatically update data in a Fusion table.  I have data coming in from an xml file and need to update the data in the Fusion table every 15 minutes, automatically.

I am well versed in JavaScript and C# and have access to SSIS.  If anyone could point me in the correct direction for accomplishing this goal, it would be appreciated.  Thanks!

===

Additional information (if required): I have research the Fusion Table API, but it seems like it is more for stand-alone web apps.  For example, when you create a client ID for OAuth 2.0, you have to give a URL.  My JavaScript or C# code will not have a URL. I just want to be able to run it and have it update the Fusion Table data every 15 minutes.

Comment: Hi, I also have similar requirements to automatically update Fusion Tables from a server behind firewall(s), but have not yet been successful in achieving the goal. My understanding is for server-to-server lash-up with no end-user intervention is need to leverage the Service Account OAuth mechanism, which requires PKCS12 keys and getting this too work is a bit complicated.

Comment: Hi, I believe you are correct.  I have setup a private key on the Google Consoles site: https://code.google.com/apis/console/  I just don't know how to use this key in C# or JavaScript to authenticate and do the work I need done.  After hours of searching, I haven't been able to find any complete examples or tutorials.

Comment: Hi again...I feel your frustration.  The documentation is a bit sketchy and bifurcated...and apparenlty can't use the OAuth playground to test out service accounts either.  There's a poster on StackOverflow named Odi and also a Google person, Kathryn Hurley, that have some helpful posts.  Also, if you haven't already seen this, watch closely (turn on the transcript and read along, as that will help) the following video on using OAuth2 service accounts with Google Drive:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iK14bfd6qhs

Comment: Thanks for this information, it was helpful.  Not much progress yet on figuring everything out, but I will post updates here.  I posted in a few other places and hope to have some answers soon.